# getJobDataMap in Quartz gives Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to put some data into Quartz job data map and access them in the class which implements the Job class. But it gives me the Null Pointer exception. When the application is run without the code which access the Job Data Map, it runs fine.

I use a Cron trigger to execute a scheduled job. In this example case, I configured it to run in each 20 seconds.

```
@Bean
public Trigger simpleJobTrigger(@Qualifier("simpleJobDetail") JobDetail jobDetail) {

    CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
    factoryBean.setName("test-trigger");
    factoryBean.setStartTime(LocalDateTime.now().toDate());
    factoryBean.setCronExpression("0/20 * * * * ?");
    factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);

    try {
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return factoryBean.getObject();

}
```

Following is my `simpleJobDetail` bean.

```
@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean simpleJobDetail() {
    JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobClass(Executor.class);
    factoryBean.setDurability(true);
    factoryBean.setName("test-job");
    factoryBean.getJobDataMap().put("caller", "James");
    return factoryBean;
}
```

This is my `execute` method.

```
public class Executor implements Job {

    @Autowired
    ScheduledTaskService scheduledTaskService;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {

        JobDataMap jobDataMap = null;
        try {
            jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getJobDataMap();
            String caller = jobDataMap.get("caller").toString();
            System.out.println("This is called by the user "+caller);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("UNABLE TO ACCESS THE JOB DATA MAP "+e);
        }

        scheduledTaskService.doThePayment();

    }
}
```

When I run the application, it prints the log given in the catch clause.

> UNABLE TO ACCESS THE JOB DATA MAP java.lang.NullPointerException

Why execute method fails to access the JobDataMap ? Is there any configuration or a property I should set? What is the reason for job map to be not available at this point?
How can I get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue in my code. 
When accessing the JobDataMap, I have accessed it in following way.

```
jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getJobDataMap();
```

instead, in my case, I should access it from JobDetails, not from the trigger.

```
jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
```